# Definitions of Active, Idle, and Disconnected Sessions in regards to Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, session

We have a couple of users that continue to get locked out.

Currently sessions never end unless a user actually locked out (from my understanding).  What are the "definitions" of the different session types?  I'm actually only really curious about the meaning of "Disconnected" unless something is screwy I'm quite confident on the meaning of active/idle.

Comment: Are you referring to TS or RDS sessions?

Comment: @joeqwerty I'm referring to the "Sessions" tab when you view a user in active directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Active: They are actively working in the session.

Idle: Session has not had any activity in x amount of minutes (I believe it's whatever the auto-lock time is from my understanding).

Disconnected: The user is not connected to the session via remote desktop. This occurs if they simply close the RD session without logging out first.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I assumed to be true, but wasn't positive.  Microsoft doesn't seem to have a good definition (that I could find).